# Python Selenium difference between Firefox and PhantomJS in scroll

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I need scroll over a web page to scrap some text, because the text is load dynamically when the user scroll over the web site (similar to facebook or twitter). Is very simple to scroll with `python`, `selenium` and `Firefox` (is only a few line of code), but the same code is not working in `phantomJS`.

I think that the problem is I can't set the window size with `phantomJS`. This is my test code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://su.org/')
print(driver.get_window_size(), driver.get_window_position())
driver.save_screenshot('imgs/firefox.png')
driver.quit()
>>> {'width': 1024, 'value': None, 'height': 555} {'value': None, 'x': 336, 'y': 28}

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://su.org/')
driver.set_window_size(width=1024, height=555)
print(driver.get_window_size(), driver.get_window_position())
driver.save_screenshot('imgs/phantom2.png')
driver.quit()
>>> {'width': 1024, 'height': 555} {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
```

It is true that the second code print the correct size, but if you see the save screenshot, the size of the second image is wrong. `PhantomJS` put all the web site in the window and I can scroll. How can I do to get the same result than `Firefox`?

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** PhantomJS's screenshot function takes a picture of the entire webpage. If your screen height (window size in Phantom's case) is only 500px but the website's height is 1000px, the screenshot's height is going to be 1000px. So the difference in `dirver.get_window_size()` and the `screenshot dimensions` might be due to this. I don't know if the same holds true for Firefox.

---

*Some pointers to help you debug:-*

- Many Content Delivery Networks have blocked PhantomJS. They can identify that you're using a headless browser. They assume that you have malicious intent and therefore do not serve CSS or JS assets and you get a blank page.
- PhantomJS does not fully support ECMA 6 script yet (24th Nov, 2016). So I've noticed that some things work on Firefox but they give out errors in PhantomJS.
- Read the PhantomJS browser logs. They contains errors, warnings etc which will help in debugging the problem. (It would be of great help if you could post the content here as well)
- Use `time.sleep(3)` to give the website some time to load the dynamic content.
- Emulate a real browser. Change the UserAgent string to match a real browser. Snippet given below.

Code:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
# code to visit and perform actions
```

- Try a different internet connection or use a proxy. Chances are that you've already requested a lot of stuff from a particular CDN.

*Good to keep in mind:-* If you're testing a web app with Phantom, try serving the assets locally rather than from a CDN. This will save you from a lot of pain as most factors are in your control.